# Outdoor Crowd Party Walla request

Tags: crowd, walla, request, sound-design

Hello everyone,

I find myself once again asking for your help with a project.
Currently, I'm editing sound fx for a feature film, and there's a rather large scene (8 or 9 minutes aprox) taking place in a house party. The catch is, the house is in the middle of nowhere. My problem doesn't comes from traffic filtering or anything, but instead with the lack of reverb from the walls.
This garden is open to the wild, so, no walls at all. I've yet to find a garden party ambience where there isn't added reverb from adjacent walls.
On top of it, there isn't much people at the party, so I believe that maybe a crowd of 10 would be perfect, given that that same crowd of 10 will be in front stereo, center channel (another take) and surround stereo (yet another take).

So, to make things clear...Do you guys have this kind of ambience lying around in your libraries? And if so, could you spare a busy worker with some of that tracks? Smaller crowds are welcome too!

I should add that we have nor the time or money to call a group walla recording for this.

Thanks again!

Gon.-

Answer (score 1):

Hi Gon, 
First of all, I think it would help to let us know which language the people are talking. Furthermore, if there's such a small group of people, is it really necessary to make it sound like a typical party? I tend to talk much softer when a party is quieter.
People behave differently in smaller groups, lower volume, lower pitch. It's not just reverb that will kill the soundtrack, also the 'tone of voice' is very important.

Also how much nature sounds can you use to mimic the surroundings and still make it sound like a party? What type of film is it? Arthouse or thriller? And what type of mood should the scene have. Did the sound supervisor or the director give you more information on that?

Also, check out other films with the same setting/mood, analyse their approach and maybe this will help you out.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Arnoud, thanks for the reply.
In picture we can assume theres a crowd of approximately 30 or 40 men and women. The catch is, when I'm cutting FX, I don't like to use 30 people in the center channel + 30 people in LR + 30 people in the surround, because, to my ears that sounds like a party of 90 people. That is why i'm going for a crowd of 10ish behaving like they're in a party of 40. I don't know if that makes it clear...
The language of the film is Spanish (I'm from Argentina), but given that the movie is veeeeryyy heavy on dialog, and it's a comedy, little of the ambiences will be really 

Comment: esposed to the viewer, to even try to understand in which lkanguage they're talking.

The scene is set in a party, taking place in a country house, where people go to trade couples. A sort of ''swinger party''.